# Add to bootstrapApplication in Angular 14 schematic

Tags: angular-schematics

With Angular 14 and standalone components, the app.module.ts can go away and instead something like this goes in main.ts instead:

```js
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule)
  ]
})
```

I'm trying to figure out how to modify that from a schematic so that I can add new modules, and specifically add modules with properties. I'm wanting to end up with this:

```js
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(
      HttpClientModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,
      EmployeeLookupModule.forRoot({
        url: 'https://www.example.com/employee'
      })
    )
  ]
})
```

Are there new methods defined somewhere that handle this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? With `NgModules`, I was able to use the ast-utils from `@schematics/angular`. Looking for something similar.

Comment: No, I just gave up.